# Making Home Page collapsed each time user is login

Tags: home-page-component, sidebar

Is it possible to make sidebar collapsed for each time the user logs in? The default state of the sidebar should be collapsed each time the user logs in. This should apply for all the users of the instance each time they logs in.

Any prompt reply will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Go to

```
Setup | Customize | User Interface | Enable Collapsible Sidebar
```

and then collapse it. That should do it. Read more [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_ui_settings.htm&language=en_US).

> The collapsible sidebar gives users the ability to show or hide the
>   sidebar on every page that normally includes the sidebar. When
>   enabled, the collapsible sidebar becomes available to all users in
>   your organization, but each user can choose his or her own preference
>   for displaying the sidebar. Users can leave the sidebar visible at all
>   times, or they can collapse the sidebar and only show it when needed
>   by clicking the edge of the collapsed sidebar.